# How to maintain the screen or display ON on the sony smarteyeglass?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

I want to maintain the screen ON on an app I have developed on the Sony Smarteyeglass. The problem is that I haven't found in the API something to set or unset. How could be done? Is it posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the setScreenState() method:

https://developer.sony.com/reference/seg-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/extension/util/control/ControlExtension#setScreenState(int)

You can pass Control.Intents#SCREEN_STATE_ON to keep the screen on.  Be careful when using this though as the battery will drain very fast with the screen on continuously.